# Firefox extension - How to show text to user from background script?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, browser-extension

This may be a very basic question, but I can't find an answer on the internet. What I'm trying to do, is showing the user some text after clicking on a context menu item. I first thought about using `alert()` but then realized, that this isn't possible in background scripts. Is there any alternative way to show some text to the user? Any ideas would be appreciated.

My background.js file:

```js
browser.contextMenus.create({
    id: "showtext",
    title: "Show text",
    contexts: ["selection"]
});

browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function (info, tab) {
    switch (info.menuItemId) {
        case "showtext":
            {
                console.log(info.selectionText);
                // alert() doesn't work here
                // looking for alternative
            }
    }
});
```

FYI: I'm trying to create a little encryption and decryption tool.

PS: I'm a beginner in extensions. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert elements into the page:

```js
const node = document.createElement('div');
node.textContent = "This page has been eaten";
document.body.appendChild(node);
```

Style it as needed for it to appear however you need.

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Modify_a_web_page

Comment: Thanks, I like your example!  That's a possible way of doing it, but I actually don't really like it, especially because I don't want to modify the page if not necessary. But I'll give it a try.

Comment: The only other way I'm aware of is displaying stuff in the things that you can open from the extension bar.

Comment: Ok, thank you  I just decided to use SweetAlert, then I don‘t have to do the styling on my own 

Answer (score 0):

#### For everyone finding this question in the future:

I ended up opening a new tab and running a script in it:

```js
browser.tabs.create({ url: "/pages/mypage.html" }).then(() => {
    browser.tabs.executeScript({
        code: "alert(`" + mytext + "`);"
    });
});
```

PS: I did not use alert, this is just an example.